# Adding a text and image on a button programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to have an text and image on a button appear dynamically - the text needs to appear on the left and the image to appear on the right. To give an example, here is an image I would like to get.

[image: ExampleButton]

After searching through a few other examples on StackOverflow, tried the following code in my activity but it doesnt seem to be working. Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong ?

**Code :**

```
btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
btn.setText("SomeText");
btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mediumTextSize);

Drawable icon= getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.cal);
icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0); //Left,Top,Right,Bottom
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, icon, null );
```

Comment: Do you want to set image on button ?

Comment: I suggest to use `ImageButton`

Comment: Else you can create `LinearLayout` and apply style

Comment: How about leaving out the two lines before the last one and just using `btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.cal, 0);` ?

Comment: @ 0X0nosugar, that method expects an int as the drawable and wont work with the way you suggested.

Comment: OK, I thought R.drawable.cal was an int value? I wanted to use the resource directly,like [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: It expects a drawable

Comment: The linked version of the method will take int values (resource identifiers)

Comment: Actually, that was not the real problem - I had the image sized wrong and that was taking up most of the space and displacing the text off the button completely showing that the button didnt have a text. My code worked once I re-adjusted the size of the image to a much smaller size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the size of the image is very important when using it on other objects - when I adjusted the image to a smaller size, my code worked fine....

The same code that I was trying earlier worked for me after resizing the image...

```
                    Button btn = new Button(this);
                    btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    btn.setText("SomeText");
                    btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mediumTextSize);
                    btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
                    Drawable icon= getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cal);
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_bg);
                    icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0); //Left,Top,Right,Bottom
                    btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, null, icon, null);
```

Thank you all for your help and suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           btn.setText("Some Text");
            btn.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
            btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);
            Drawable myDrawable = 
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cancel_black_24dp);
            btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,myDrawable,null);
```